# Adding Basic Monitoring Package to Virtual Guest via API

Tags: monitoring, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is it possible to add a monitoring package through the Softlayer API. On the portal, I can go into the Monitoring section and Order a "Monitoring Package - Basic", which will associate it with that Virtual Guest.

Is it possible to do this either during the placeOrder call or after the initial placeOrder call (i.e if the customer wants to add Basic Monitoring after the server is provisioned).

I tried to look into examples but they all assumed that there was a monitoring agent available, but it wasnt in my case. I also looked into [Going Further with Softlayer part 3](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3) but not sure how to extract the Basic Monitoring package from Product_Package Service.

Im using Python to do this, so any pointers in associating a Monitoring service during creation or after-creation would be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
"""
Order a Monitoring Package

Build a SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Monitoring_Package object for a new
monitoring order and pass it to the SoftLayer_Product_Order API service to order it
In this care we'll order a Basic (Hardware and OS) package with Basic Monitoring Package - Linux
configuration for more details see below

Important manual pages:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Monitoring_Package
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent_Configuration_Template_Group

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

"""
Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Monitoring_Package object
containing the order you wish to place.
"""
oderTemplate = {
    'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Monitoring_Package',
    'packageId': 0,  # the packageID for order monitoring packages is 0
    'prices': [
        {'id': 2302}  # this is the price for Monitoring Package - Basic ((Hardware and OS))
    ],
    'quantity': 0,  # the quantity for order a service (in this case monitoring package) must be 0
    'sendQuoteEmailFlag': True,
    'useHourlyPricing': True,
    'virtualGuests': [
        {'id': 4906034}  # the virtual guest ID where you want add the monitoring package
    ],
    'configurationTemplateGroups': [
        {'id': 3}  # the templateID for the monitoring group (in this case Basic Monitoring package for Unix/Linux operating system.)
    ]
}

# Declare the API client to use the SoftLayer_Product_Order API service
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
productOrderService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order']

"""
verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with a call to
placeOrder() when you're ready to order. Both calls return a receipt object
that you can use for your records.

Once your order is placed it'll go through SoftLayer's provisioning process.
"""
try:
    order = productOrderService.verifyOrder(oderTemplate)
    print(order)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to verify the order! faultCode=%s, faultString=%s"
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

this is an example to create an network monitoring

```
"""
Create network monitoring

The script creates a monitoring network with Service ping
in a determinate IP address

Important manual pages
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer.API
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'


# The ID of the server you wish to monitor
serverId = 7698842

"""
ID of the query type which can be found with SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host_Stratum/getAllQueryTypes.
This example uses SERVICE PING: Test ping to address, will not fail on slow server response due to high latency or
high server load
"""
queryTypeId = 1

# IP address on the previously defined server to monitor
ipAddress = '10.104.50.118'

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
networkMonitorVersion = client['SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host']

# Define the SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host templateObject.
newMonitor = {
    'guestId': serverId,
    'queryTypeId': queryTypeId,
    'ipAddress': ipAddress
}

# Send the request for object creation and display the return value
try:
    result = networkMonitorVersion.createObject(newMonitor)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to create new network monitoring "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try this

Comment: Just in case I added another example to create a network monitoring with service ping maybe that one also helps you regards